# Battery Shows Always Charging Even it's not plugged in

Tags: battery

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
but my battery indicator is showing plugged in even it's not.
it can't detect low battery.
please help.
new user.

Comment: what machine are you using?

Comment: Check for a BIOS update at the manufacturer's web site.

Comment: it's Asus E202SA.
and it works fine on windows.
i don't know if it's a bios problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you reinstall or update your unity battery status level or gnome battery status shell extension.

Also check the battery status via command line in your terminal

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

If it says the battery is plugged even if it's not, I guess it's a more a BIOS related issue.

Comment: how to reinstall or update your unity battery status level or gnome battery status shell extension ?

Comment: Use gnome or unity tweak tool, or firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

this is battery status.
and there was a slight mistake.
i thought the indicator was frozen as plugged in.
then i turned my laptop off unplugged the charger and started again.
this time it's showing discharging.
and if i plug in my charger now it still says discharging.
again i turned my laptop off and started again with charger plugged in and it says plugged in now even if i remove the charger.
please help. i have some other issues to solve too.
don't want to get stuck at this one.

### this is my battery status:

> native-path:         BAT0
>    vendor:              ASUSTeK
>    model:               E202-42
>    power supply:        yes
>    updated:             শুক্রবার 09 জুন 2017 10:11:21 অপরাহ্ণ BDT (84 seconds ago)
>    has history:         yes
>    has statistics:      yes
>    battery
>
> present:            yes
>      rechargeable:       yes
>      state:              discharging
>      warning-level:      none
>      energy:             20.007 Wh
>      energy-empty:       0 Wh
>      energy-full:        44.95 Wh
>      energy-full-design: 48.336 Wh
>      energy-rate:        8.059 W
>      voltage:            11.4 V
>      time to empty:      2.5 hours
>      percentage:         44%
>      capacity:           92.9949%
>      technology:         lithium-ion
>      icon-name:         'battery-good-symbolic'
>    History (rate):
>
> 1497024681 8.059 discharging